# How can I change the color of clouds?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor

I created a scene using a bunch of clouds from the Cloud addon that comes with blender. I played around with the nodes but I cant find a way to change the color of the clouds? Also The clouds in the foreground seem to generate some weird dark border, I wonder why that is as well.

[image: Screenshot]